# How to split a csv string to multiple values

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm using vertica, and I'm having trouble trying to split entries into multiple ones. For clarification, consider the following example. Suppose I have the following table entries (let's call it pizza_toppings)

```
customer_name | order_date | toppings
--------------+------------+----------
sally         | 1/1/2011   | peppers, olives
mike          | 2/2/2011   | pepperoni, mushrooms
```

How do I split the toppings entries into multiple rows? The following table is what I want:

```
customer_name | order_date | toppings
--------------+------------+----------
sally         | 1/1/2011   | peppers
sally         | 1/1/2011   | olives
mike          | 2/2/2011   | pepperoni
mike          | 2/2/2011   | mushrooms
```

I've been looking around multiple forums and I've come across SPLIT_PART, but that requires you to know how many parts there are in the delimited entry. On top of that, I don't know how to use that within an INSERT.

Thanks.

Comment: why not have the toppings in a separate table and have a foreign key to vour main record?

Comment: What's foreign key? Sorry I'm new to this. Let's assume that I'm given the first table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy with Vertica's txt index package. Suppose you have a table like this:

```
SQL> select * from stest;
 customer_name | order_date |       toppings       
---------------+------------+----------------------
 sally         | 2011-01-01 | peppers, olives
 Robert        | 2011-04-04 | olives
 mike          | 2011-02-02 | pepperoni, mushrooms
 John          | 2011-03-03 | one, two, three
(4 rows)
```

You can use the following SQL to get what you're looking for:

```
SQL> select customer_name, order_date, trim(words) as toppings from (
       select customer_name, order_date,   
              v_txtindex.StringTokenizerDelim(toppings,',')  
                over(partition by customer_name, order_date) 
       from stest ) a ;
 customer_name | order_date | toppings  
---------------+------------+-----------
 mike          | 2011-02-02 | pepperoni
 mike          | 2011-02-02 | mushrooms
 Robert        | 2011-04-04 | olives
 sally         | 2011-01-01 | peppers
 sally         | 2011-01-01 | olives
 John          | 2011-03-03 | one
 John          | 2011-03-03 | two
 John          | 2011-03-03 | three
(8 rows)
```

In case you didn't install the txt index package... As dbadmin:

```
$ cd /opt/vertica/packages/txtindex/ddl
$ vsql -f install.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @mauro. I'm trying to implement the equivalent answer, but I'm getting the following error: ERROR 2521:  Cannot specify anything other than user defined transforms and partitioning expressions in the SELECT list. I think it's referring to indicating different column names along with the StringTokenizerDelim() within the inner SELECT. I've been trying to google the cause, but can't find anything. Would you happen to know? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind. I think I figured out that problem. I needed to add a PARTITION BY within the OVER() clause.